# Connect 4 add element from User in LIST PYTHON

Tags: python, list, matrix, connect-four

I have created the matrix, but when the data entered by the user is added the board loses the initial structure

**I need the board to continue printing in the same format as when the game starts.**

This is the code:

```
tablero = []
NUM_FILAS = 6
NUM_COLUM = 7
jugador = 1


for fila in range(NUM_FILAS):
    filas = []
    for j in range(NUM_COLUM):
        filas.append([])
    tablero.append(filas)

print("\nJueguemos CONECTA 4\n")
for i in range(6):
    for j in range(7):
        print(tablero[i][j], end=" ")
    print()

while True:
    
    usuario = input('Jugador, elige una columna: ')
    if usuario.isdigit():
        usuario = int(usuario)
        
        for pos in tablero:
             if usuario == 1:
                tablero.append([jugador])
                print(tablero)
                break

else:
    print('El juego solo funciona con numeros')
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: The first table is printed line by line, the 2nd globally: you could implement a tprint(table) function that prints the table line by line (with the code after "print("\nJueguemos CONECTA 4\n")") then use it each time you want to print the board.

Comment: def tprint(table): for i in range(6): for j in range(7): print(table[i][j], end=" ") print() , then tprint(tablero) everywhere instead of print(tablero). You should probably do something for your table to print prettily (since [] and [1] don't have the same width).